# PHPExcel calculateWorksheetDimension of a csv file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I use PHPExcel to import data from a .csv file which has the same rows and columns with a excel file. Basically I open them with LibreOffice and they look the same. However there are two result when calculating theirs worksheet dimensions.

1. csv: A1:A10
2. xlsx: A1: AMK10

I just want to ask that it is always like that due to the different formats or I do something wrong?

```
$pi = pathinfo($filePath);
  switch ($pi['extension']) {
    case 'xls':
      $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
      break;
    case 'xlsx':
      $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
      break;
    case 'csv':
      $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');
      break;
    default:
      return array();
  }
  $phpexcel = $reader->load($filePath);
  $sheet = $phpexcel->getActiveSheet();
  $sheet->calculateWorksheetDimension();
```

Comment: It looks as though there is something in cell AMK10, even if it's just a style setting or a null value.... use `calculateWorksheetDataDimension()` instead of `calculateWorksheetDimension()` to see what the highest cell address that actually contains data is

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried, but the result still the same :-?

Comment: In that case, there's some actual content in cell AMK10, even if it's simply a null value or an empty string

Comment: Actually, the grid dimension is A1:AI10, not that much. But in csv file, PHPExcel only return the first column (A1:A10) of the file.

Comment: Is the separator in your csv file a comma? If not, then you need to tell the CSV reader what the separator is before loading the file

Comment: In that case: `$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV'); $reader->setDelimiter(';');`

Comment: OK it works, thank you so much :D. I think you should make it an answer :yes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading a CSV file, if the delimiter isn't a default comma (`,`) then you need to explicitly set the delimiter for the reader. e.g.

```
PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV'); 
$reader->setDelimiter(';');
```